# implementing sharepoint permissions by content type

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-on-prem, item-level-permissions

I am working with SharePoint server 2013 on premises. Regarding one of the implementations, I am using an OOTB custom list. For permissions, I have it setup by SharePoint groups: Finance Members, HR Members, Accounting Members to name a few.

Now based on the design requirement, I am going to create 3 content types as follows: Finance, HR and Accounting and then create separate list views for each of these content types so if users click on Accounting view, they only see Accounting content type relevant list items.

Now the challenge i have is and I am not sure if this is possible to do or not, ideally HR Members should only see list items relevant to HR content type, similarly Accounting members should only see items relevant to Accounting content type and so on. So basically implementing permissions by content type using SP groups.

Now is this possible to do by some sort of JS/JQ solution which can be added in a script editor web part and make it work? Or any other type of solution. If possible please share the code.

P.S: I agree its not possible to do this OOTB, so looking for code solution. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I propose following OOTB ways:

1. Create 3 lists and setup unique permissions for each one. Then aggregate data from 3 lists using CQWP
2. Create 3 folder within the list, setup unique permissions for each one (using advanced button), set default content type for each one, create view and show all items without folders.

Comment: I am not looking to do data aggregation here and folder approach will not work in my requirement, thanks.